# Android Plugin UnitySendMessage Never Called

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

This was working a few weeks ago, but now I've noticed my `OnReward` message is no longer called from my custom plugin.

In my rewardcenter.cs class I call the plugin class to set the listener to the gameObject that this script is attached to (in this example case it's `GameObject`):

```
public class rewardcenter : MonoBehaviour {
    int counter = 0;
    void Start () {

        OnReward("85");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (counter == 20) {
            #if UNITY_ANDROID 
                PluginClass.SetRewardListener(gameObject.name);
                Debug.Log("Adding Android Reward Listener: " + gameObject.name);
            #endif
        }

        counter++;
    }

    void OnReward(string quantity)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnReward: " + quantity);
    }
}
```

In the PluginClass.cs file you can see how I call the `setUnityObjectName` call on the java plugin class to set the unity object to the passed in GameObject's name string `GameObject`:

```
private static AndroidJavaObject pluginClassInstance = null;
private static AndroidJavaObject activityContext = null;

// pass in the GameObject that implements the OnReward method
public static void SetRewardListener(string gameObjName)
{
    if (activityContext == null) {
        using (AndroidJavaClass activityClass = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) {
            activityContext = activityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("currentActivity");
        }
    }

    using (AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass ("pluginclass.com.PluginClass")) {
        if (pluginClass != null) {
            pluginClassInstance = pluginClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("getInstance");
            activityContext.Call ("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable (() => {
                pluginClassInstance.Call("setUnityObjectName", gameObjName);
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

In the java PluginClass itself later on we attempt to call `OnReward` using `UnitySendMessage` on our game object:

```
   public void unityEarnedReward(String quantity) {
        Log.d(TAG, "unityEarnedReward: " + quantity);
        if (PluginClass.getInstance()._unityObjectName != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "calling OnReward(" + quantity + ") on unityObject with name: " + PluginClass.getInstance()._unityObjectName);
            com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(PluginClass.getInstance()._unityObjectName, "OnReward", quantity);
        }
    }
```

I end up with a log output in Android Studio of:

```
calling OnReward(202) on unityObject with name: GameObject
```

But it never seems to actually call `OnReward` within the game.

Just for kicks I tried calling `OnReward` when the script starts, it ends up with an output of:

```
OnReward: 85
```

So I know it works and prints to the console when it is executed.

Any idea where I'm going wrong? The weird thing is this worked a few weeks ago, but now the `OnReward` method isn't executed.

EDIT:

I also tried running it without the specific class declaration like this with no luck:

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(PluginClass.getInstance()._unityObjectName, "OnReward", quantity);
```

I also renamed my gameObject to be `MyCustomPlugin` but while the android code triggered it doesn't seem the `OnReward` method was ever triggered on the script linked to `MyCustomPlugin`.

Screenshot of script:
[image]

When I run this code:

```
void Update ()
    {
        var unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        unityPlayer.CallStatic ("UnitySendMessage", gameObject.name, "OnReward", "185");

        OnReward ("86"); 
    }
```

I end up with two Log messages:

```
04-14 10:47:47.085 10341-10354/? I/Unity: OnReward: 86

                                          (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
04-14 10:47:47.095 10341-10354/? I/Unity: OnReward: 185

                                          (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
```

Comment: Does the GameOjbect even exist? Maybe you renamed it.... You can verify by using `Log.d` on `TheoremReach.getInstance()._unityObjectName`. On Unity side, use `GameObject.Find` to verify that this GameOjbect you are sending the event to actually exist.

Comment: Yep, they both exist. When I do it on the Unity side I get `GameObject` as the name, and I get the same string when I `Log.d` it out in Android. Good check though!

Comment: Do you have more than 1 "GameObject" Object with the same name in the game? I think your name is too common, have you tried renaming your object to something like  "MyCustomPlugin"

Comment: Good thought. I renamed it to MyCustomPlugin and got `calling OnReward(101) on unityObject with name: MyCustomPlugin` but the actual `OnReward` call wasn't made. I also verified it was the correct gameObject on the Unity side :(

Comment: When you are logging, you are using PluginClass.getInstance()._unityObjectName, when you are actually calling the function, you are using TheoremReach.getInstance()._unityObjectName in the above example. Might be a typo, but just incase?

Comment: Ah good catch. Technically TheoremReach is the PluginClass - I just cleaned up the example a bit. I updated the question

Comment: Could you confirm that your `GameObject` _MyCustomPlugin_ has the `rewardcenter` script attached to it?

Comment: Yep - screenshot updated.

Comment: Let's rule out something with the plugin class or Java layer. Try calling it from the C# side with the following code:

using (var unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
{ 
  unityPlayer.CallStatic("UnitySendMessage", gameObject.name, "OnReward", 85);
}

Comment: Updated with results. When we do CallStatic like that it does work.

Comment: Is the GameObject instantiated before the plugin is calling SendMessage? If it's not a race condition it definitely sounds like something is dying when called from the plugin.

Although any errors would show up in logcat, which you are looking at.

Comment: I believe so. The plugin is initiated in a script attached to the game object and it gets passed the `gameobject.name` as reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the fundamental problem is that because I have a separate activity, it pauses the UnityActivity which in turn pauses Unity.

Thus Unity cannot receive the UnitySendMessage when I was trying to send it.

To get around this I implemented a way to call it in my `onStop` method of my Activity. At this point Unity is no longer paused and can receive the message.

Comment: Unity jumping to another activity might not be something, I would try my best to avoid jumping activity, maybe  extend unityplayeractivity and do things inside.

Comment: Can AndroidJavaProxy work if unityplayer is paused?